# Swift stop an SKAction.repeatForever within a function?

Tags: swift, background, sprite-kit, skaction

I'm trying to stop my background from moving upon collision.

This is what creates and moves the background:

```
 let bgTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "bg.png")
    let moveBGanimation = SKAction.move(by: CGVector(dx: 0, dy: -bgTexture.size().height), duration: 4)
    let shiftBGAnimation = SKAction.move(by: CGVector(dx: 0, dy: bgTexture.size().height), duration: 0)
    let moveBGForever = SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.sequence([moveBGanimation, shiftBGAnimation]))

    var i: CGFloat = 0

    while i < 3 {

        bg = SKSpriteNode(texture: bgTexture)
        bg.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y: bgTexture.size().height * i)
        bg.size.width = self.frame.width
        bg.zPosition = -2

        bg.run(moveBGForever)
        self.addChild(bg)

        i += 1


    }
```

How can I stop bg.run(moveBGForever? I've tried bg.removeAllActions() and also tried adding it to a key but this doesn't do anything.

```
if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.object.rawValue || contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.object.rawValue {



}
```

Comment: You should maintain the first while cycle code instead of change your question with my solution otherwise all the thread become incomprehensible, you should add to the last part of your question  your updates..

Comment: Yes of course, I've reverted it back now! How can a key be added to a repeat action with  a count? ".repeat(yourBgActions, count:3)"

Comment: Yes, you should create another action `SKAction.repeat` where you can put a count number. When you have did it, you launch `self.run(actionRepeated,withKey: "yourKey")`

Comment: Added: self.run(actionRepeated,withKey: "yourKey"). Upon collision I've tried  removeAction(forKey: "yourKey") but not working

Comment: have you tried self.removeAction(forKey:...) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happened because you shouldn't create a `while` cycle to repeat an action, but you must simply create a:

```
let myCode = SKAction.run{
    bg = SKSpriteNode(texture: bgTexture)
    bg.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y: bgTexture.size().height * i)
    bg.size.width = self.frame.width
    bg.zPosition = -2
    ...
}
let actionRepeated = SKAction.repeat(mycode,count:3)
```

In your case, you can repeat this action 3 times.
After that, you can run or stop this `actionRepeated` giving to it a key, whenever you need to stop it.

Comment: So I should replace let moveBGForever = SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.sequence([moveBGanimation, shiftBGAnimation])) with .repeat? What count would I set this to if I need it repeat continuously however?

Comment: I don't speak about your repeatForever sub action, I speak about your "while cycle".

Comment: Remember that you can do let myCode = SKAction.run{ ... code ... } instead of you while cycle, then you repeat this action with SKAction.repeat..

Comment: Which part is the while cycle Alessendaro? Is it the moveBGForever?

Comment: I understand! So as I've now edited in my first post?

Comment: It's hard to say because you don't respect the the code indentation but seems correct..

Answer (score 1):

You'd probably need to restructure your code. Instead of using your 'while' cycle:

```
while i < 3 {
...
}
```

you should use the `.repeat(yourBgActions, count:3)`.

Comment: How can a key be added to a repeat action with a count? ".repeat(yourBgActions, count:3)"

Comment: You make an instance of this SKAction: `let repeatAction = SKAction.repeat(yourBgActions, count:3)`.  Then you can add a key to repeatAction.

Comment: Added: self.run(actionRepeated,withKey: "yourKey"). Upon collision I've tried removeAction(forKey: "yourKey") but not working

Comment: @AlexIngram You should try to remove the action on the same node that you were started it.